# Order confirmation mail sent on order cancellation Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, magento1.9.3

When a user adds a product in his cart and clicks to checkout and select the PayPal method.

He redirected to PayPal site for payment and for some reason if he cancels the order, he gets redirected to cart page with cancel order notification and in admin cancel order stored.

But the issue is that the user gets the order confirmation mail.

I am unable to debug anything in this.

I am using Magento 1.9.3.10

Answer (score 0):

When a user is leaving the magento site, the order has been created for under magento. As per system, the order has been placed without payment, In this process, the customer is getting an email. You have to disable the email sent/comment the order email code and need to sent email on checkout success event

Comment: but no email sent when user leaves site, mail sent only when user cancel order in paypal and get back to cart page